# Unable to Customize EditForm.aspx with Document Sets in SharePoint 2010

Tags: content-type, document-set

I give...I am hoping someone has a good answer.

I create a content type based on a Document Set (called A). I create a document library and allow this new custom content type to be added to the library. I add one column (say Car Phone) to the new content type(A).

I want to be able to edit the EditForm.aspx to add some text or javascript.

However, if I do anything to the editform.aspx through SharePoint designer it completely ignores any custom fields on my content type A. Now, when selecting the item, and selecting edit i do not see my Car Phone Property. This occurs only when i do anything to the editform.aspx that exists in the document library. Just copying to a new name and setting as the default edit form it ignores my custom properties on the content type A>

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You try to add that new column to the content type and not to the library.

Comment: Yes, my content type was defined at the site level and was added to a document library.  After adding the content type the edit works fine with all the properties however if i try to modify editform in any way it then just completely ignores any of my addition columns on the content type.